# Selecting data from multiple tables and use a left join?

Tags: mysql, join

I have a query which doesnt work and it's strating to drive me crazy ;). Basically this is what I'm trying to achieve:

```
SELECT
  table1.field1,
  table1.field2,
  table2.field1,
  table3.field1
FROM
  table1,
  table2
LEFT JOIN
  table3
ON table3.field1 = table2.field1
```

But for some reason I'm unable to execute this query. I believe this is because of the join being executed after telling to select from multiple tables. Because this query works when I select from 1 table.

Can someone tell me what to do when I want to select from multiple tables and use joins?

Comment: Is there any relationship between table1 and table2?

Comment: Could you please post some sample data for `table1`, `table2`, `table3` and desired output of the query?

Comment: What do you mean by "unable to execute this query"? Does it give you an error? The syntax looks correct

Comment: The problem is solved, thanks for helping out. +1 to your comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want a JOIN and `ON` clause for your first join. Something like:

```
SELECT 
  t1.field1, 
  t1.field2, 
  t2.field1, 
  t3.field1 
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2 on t1.ID = t2.ID
LEFT JOIN table3 t3 ON t3.field1 = t2.field1
```

Note, the INNER JOIN may need to be a LEFT JOIN, it is not clear from your question.

Comment: That was indeed the problem, only I didn't knew I could select from multiple tables and use joins in between the tables. Thanks again +1 and accepted.

Answer (score 3):

You are missing a `JOIN` condition between `table1` and `table2`:

```
SELECT  table1.field1,
        table1.field2,
        table2.field1,
        table3.field1
FROM    table1
LEFT JOIN
        table2
ON      table2.id = table1.id
LEFT JOIN
        table3
ON      table3.field1 = table2.field1
```

Comment: You're right, but I can only accept 1 answer as accepted. +1 though! Thank you.